# Alternative of Bitwise operation in sql query to achieve index seek

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance

Let suppose there is a table having two fields `"id"` and `"value"`. I have created a `non-clustured index on "value"` field There is a parameter `"@valueToCompare"`.

```
For example : 
MyTable
Id(Int) Value(int)
1       9
2       11
3       13
4       7
5       8
6       20

@valueToCompare = 27
```

Now I want to write a query which will give me the resultset which satisfy `"value & @valueToCompare = value"` condition
Hence my query will is

`select * from MyTable where value & @valueToCompare = value`

which will give the result after calculating

```
9 & 27   =9
11 & 27  =11
13 & 27  =9
7 & 27   =3
8 & 27   =8
20 & 27  =16
```

Now the problem with this query is that the optimizer will do `index scan rather than Index seek`, hence less efficient.

So wanted to know is there a way to write the query to achieve index seek.

**NOTE : I Will use the result set in c# code**

Comment: How many different bit flags do you have?

Comment: it can be anything between o to int.MaxValue

Comment: In other words, it's 31 individual bits, right?

Comment: Yes it is, I have shown an example too in my question

Answer (score 1):

Index seek may or may not be more efficient than scan. Scaning a narrow covering index will probably be faster than seek&lookup, except for the highest selective queries.

A single bit column can only be 0 or 1; it's selectivity is 50% on average, so probably not a very good candidate for indexing. You can create an index, but taking into account very high cost of lookups it may or may not be used by the optimizer.

Combining it into a bitfield might be better solution, even more if you know your data and order the bits cleverly, from higher selectivity to lower. To illustrate the idea:

```
select * from MyTable where value < @valueToCompare and value & @valueToCompare = value
```

Comment: in my case value will be always less than @valueToCompare, so this will not help.

Comment: So, @valueToCompare will never be, say, 13?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not use indexes to perform bitwise operations.  You are out of luck, however you could maybe start by first creating a smaller resultset via a CTE or derived table and then perform the operation on a smaller set.

Comment: I am writting the sql query in c#, so I don't thing this will be helpful. right?

Comment: that won't make any difference with respect to the use of an index no.

Comment: Okay, in my case there is no condition which will shorten the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current value of `@valueToCompare` participates in an expression with one of the columns, there is no way to convert this to an index seek. However, you could potentially get a much faster lookup if you are willing to split the individual flags into their own columns.

To represent `int`s from 0 to `int.MaxValue` you would need 31 bit columns - say, `v0` through `v30`, inclusuve. You can make an index on them, and then split the search number into individual bits, and run your query. Instead of `value & @valueToCompare = value` you would write a combination of checks corresponding to `@valueToCompare`'s binary value.

For example, if `@valueToCompare` is 9<sub>10</sub> or 1001<sub>2</sub>, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE v0=1 AND v3=1
```

`v0` is the column containing bit zero; `v3` is the column containing bit three. These are the two bits set in the binary representation of nine.

Rather than managing the columns manually, you could let SQL Server manage them for you.

```
create table bitfields (
id int,
value int,
v0 as value & 1 persisted,
v1 as value & 2 persisted,
v2 as value & 4 persisted,
v3 as value & 8 persisted,
v4 as value & 16 persisted,
v5 as value & 32 persisted,
v6 as value & 64 persisted,
v7 as value & 128 persisted
-- ...and so on
)
create index bitfields_idx on bitfields (v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
```

Now you can search based on bitfied values that have been separated out for you. The query for the `value & 9 = 9` on this table would look like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE v0=1 AND v3=8
```

The value to which you compare `vN` is 2<sup>N</sup>, so for `v0` it's `1`, for `v1` it's `2`, for `v2` it's `4`, for `v3` it's `8`, and so on.

Comment: This seems to be a good idea but making 31 different column for this doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Learning Why doesn't it make sense? If you have so much data that an index scan vs. an index seek is a big deal to you, making 31 columns is a reasonable price to pay for a great deal of speed-up that you are going to see.

Comment: what if i have similar type of two or three more fields, There should be other way, like creating a temptable and putting all combination of @valueToCompare, but that will be also tidies, I know there must be a best way to do it.

Comment: @Learning If you need several fields like this, it would be a good time to put your flags into a separate table: even 31 is borderline, but once you reach 40, it become crazy.

Comment: Okay, I will try to use this way, but something else we can do here?

Comment: @Learning You could make these columns computed, and index them. Let me see if I could build a small demo...

Comment: I will be very grateful. Thanks for your help :)